# Multiplayer - invite friend stuck in waiting even after accepting the invitation

Tags: iphone, game-center, multiplayer

I am developing  a game with multiplayer using game center, my problem is that when I press play now and do the same with other device, the game center makes a match and end up properly but when i send an invitation to a player it just got stuck in waiting and connecting...

it never connects the initiated player to invited player.

Any Solutions ?

Thanks in Advance !!

```
- (void)addInvitationHandler{
    GlobalController *gc = [GlobalController shared];

    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {
        // Insert application-specific code here to clean up any games in progress.
        if (acceptedInvite)
        {
            GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
            mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = gc.renderer;
            [gc.renderer matchmakerShow:mmvc];

        }
        else if (playersToInvite)
        {
            GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
            request.minPlayers = 2;
            request.maxPlayers = 2;
            request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;

            GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
            mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = gc.renderer;

            [gc.renderer matchmakerShow:mmvc];

        }
    };

}
```

this is code i am using for accepting the invitation and sending the invitation.